# Dynamically loading Gridview not displaying and data

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I'm trying to load a grid from data retrieved from an Active Directory. I've set out the GridView as below. The problem is the records are being created but the data is not showing

```
<asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="True" Visible="false"
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
    style ="z-index: 2; left: 65px; top:355px; position: absolute; height: 221px; width: 1158px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee No">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="EmployeeNo" runat="server" style="color:blue"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="DisplayName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="Department" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>           
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job Title">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="JobTitle" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Manager">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Manager" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>           
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

I run the function below before gathering the Active Data

```
    private void SetInitialRow()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EmployeeNo", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DisplayName", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Department", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("JobTitle", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Manager", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
        dr["EmployeeNo"] = string.Empty;
        dr["DisplayName"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Department"] = string.Empty;
        dr["JobTitle"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Manager"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Name"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        //dr = dt.NewRow();

        //Store the DataTable in ViewState
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

        Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
    }
```

Then I declare my DataTable like this

```
 SetInitialRow();
 DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
 DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
```

Then I loop through the Active Data records

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyVars.NoOfADRecords; i++)
{
    Label empNo = (Label)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("EmployeeNo");
    Label displayName =(Label)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("DisplayName");
    Label dept =(Label)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("Department");
    Label jobTitle = (Label)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("JobTitle");
    Label manager = (Label)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("Manager");
    Label name = (Label)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("Name");

    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i;

    empNo.Text = MyVars.ADEmployeeID[i];
    displayName.Text = MyVars.ADName[i];
    dept.Text = MyVars.ADDepartment[i];
    jobTitle.Text = MyVars.ADJobtitle[i];
    manager.Text = MyVars.ADManager[i];
    name.Text = MyVars.ADName[i];

    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["EmployeeNo"] = empNo.Text;
    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["DisplayName"] = displayName.Text;
    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Department"] = dept.Text;
    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["JobTitle"] = jobTitle.Text;
    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Manager"] = manager.Text;
    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Name"] = name.Text;

    dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;
}
```

As it is now it crashes on the first loop, if I replace the i with 0 like this

```
(Label)Gridview1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("EmployeeNo");
```

It works but although all of the records display there is no data. When I step though the code in debug the empNo.text etc.. all have values, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem might simply be that you are calling GridView1.DataBind() too soon.  Try calling GridView1.DataBind() **last**, after you've finished adding all the rows to dtCurrentTable.

Comment: Thank you Joe, both you and the other answers were correct and very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding empty rows into datatable. Replace the code below to add rows into datatable

```
    drCurrentRow["EmployeeNo"] = empNo.Text;
    drCurrentRow["DisplayName"] = displayName.Text;
    drCurrentRow["Department"] = dept.Text;
    drCurrentRow["JobTitle"] = jobTitle.Text;
    drCurrentRow["Manager"] = manager.Text;
    drCurrentRow["Name"] = name.Text;

    dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;
```

Instead of your code

```
    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["EmployeeNo"] = empNo.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["DisplayName"] = displayName.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Department"] = dept.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["JobTitle"] = jobTitle.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Manager"] = manager.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Name"] = name.Text;
dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the DataTable in the `SetInitialRow` method. When you are binding there, it only adds the one empty row to the GridView.
You should do the databinding AFTER the loop to get all the users...

Second you try to find controls in the GridView where there are none, then cast to `Label`, set the Label text from `MyVars.NoOfADRecords` and add those to the DataTable. Better to add the values directly to the DataTable like in the snippet below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyVars.NoOfADRecords; i++)
{
    drCurrentRow["EmployeeNo"] = MyVars.ADEmployeeID[i];
    drCurrentRow["DisplayName"] = MyVars.ADName[i];

    dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
}

Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
Gridview1.DataBind();
ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;
```

But it you want to get rid of a lot of unnecessary code, just do this:

```
Gridview1.DataSource = MyVars.NoOfADRecords;
Gridview1.DataBind();

<ItemTemplate>
    <%# Eval("EmployeeNo") %>
</ItemTemplate>
```